# How to add color to a plot based on a different column from a data set in R?

Tags: r, plot

everyone,

I have the following data set (called demo).

```
    Nation   GDP FHouse OECD   regime
1   Albania  3719    4.5    0 not free
2   Algeria  5327    5.5    0 not free
3    Angola  1462    6.0    0 not free
4 Argentina 12095    1.5    0     free
5   Armenia  2421    4.0    0 not free
6 Australia 27390    1.0    1     free
```

I made a plot make a plot of GDP and Fhouse.

```
plot(demo$GDP, demo$FHouse, xlab = "Country's GDP", ylab = "Freedom House Rating", pch=16, xlim = c(500,5000), family="serif")
```

Now, I am being asked to color each point based on regime (free,not free, partly free). I've been reading, and apparently I can use ifelse, however, I don't know how to give it three conditions so that each country is colored based on free, not free, and partly free.

Thank you all.

Comment: an easier way is to use `factors`: `plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, col = factor(gear))` you can also set custom colors this way: `plot(mpg ~ wt, mtcars, col = c('red', 'blue', 'orange')[factor(gear)])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with base R plotting you can do :

```
demo$color <- ifelse(demo$regime == 'free', 'red', 
                ifelse(demo$regime == 'not free', 'yellow', 'green'))

plot(demo$GDP, demo$FHouse, xlab = "Country's GDP", 
      ylab = "Freedom House Rating", pch=16, family="serif", col = demo$color)
```

With `ggplot2` :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(demo) + 
  aes(GDP, FHouse, color = regime) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: This might be a good use for `switch(demo$regime, free="red", notfree="yellow", "green")`.

Comment: Or just plot using the `factor` - `c("red","blue","black")[factor(demo$regime)]` or even `factor(demo$regime)` if you've already set the palette

Comment: Doesn't switch work only with scalars? I might have to use `switch` with `sapply` I guess.

Comment: Shoot, right, ... `sapply(switch, demo$regime, free="red", ...)`